# MongoDB - Update One Field or Another

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, upsert

I'm pretty new to MongoDB so this might be my inexperience with it. I'm trying to do an `upsert` that when a record is found it will update multiple fields based on multiple conditions.

I have the following record in a collection:

```js
{
  modelId: "5e68c7eaa0887971ea6ef54c",
  versionId: 999,
  timeStamp: "1/1/2020",
  oldValue: 'Blue',
  newValue: 'Red'
}
```

I'm trying to satisfy the following conditions with a single `upsert` statement in order to avoid making multiple trips to the DB (based on the query that a document matching the `modelId` and `versionId` is found:

1. If `timeStamp` of new record is before (`lt`) the existing document then update `oldValue`
2. If `timeStamp` of new record is after (`gt`) the existing document then update `newValue`
3. If matching records is not found insert the new record.

In psuedo code terms I'm trying to do this with the `upsert` statement:

```c#
existingRecord = item in collection matching modelId and versionId

if(existingRecord = null)
{
   //insert newRecord
}
if(newRecord.timeStamp < existingRecord.timeStamp)
{
   existingRecord.oldValue = newRecord.oldValue
   existingRecord.timeStamp = newRecord.timeStamp
}
else if(newRecord.timeStamp > existingRecord.timeStamp)
{
   existingRecord.newValue = newRecord.newValue
   existingRecord.timeStamp = newRecord.timeStamp
}
```

I've seen the possibility to do an `upsert` based on the condition of a date, something like:

```
db.collection.update( { id:o.id, date: { $lt:o.date } }, {$set : { o }}, {upsert:true} );
```

I don't know how to expand that to be able to update either the `oldValue` or the `newValue` based on the `timeStamp` value.

I'm planning on having a good amount of records inserted into the collection every day, estimate around 1MM, I'd hate to have to do a `find()` and then an `update()` for each record.

I'm using Mongo 4.0 and would appreciate any advice.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, in **version 4.0**, you are not allowed to use the conditions in the update query. Hence, you end up firing two queries instead.

```
db.collection.update({condition}, { $set: { o } }, { multi: true ,upsert:true });
db.collection.update({!condition}, { $set: { n } }, { multi: true ,upsert:true });
```

---

However, in **version 4.2**, added [db.collection.update](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/method/db.collection.update/index.html#update-method-agg-pipeline) pipeline, in which the aggregation is allowed.

And, it contains only the following aggregation stages:

```
$addFields and its alias $set
$project and its alias $unset
$replaceRoot and its alias $replaceWith.
```

Hope this will help :)

**Update**

I have added the `$set` stage to update the document. It will update the if timestamp condition is true else it will not update. and applies the same for other condition.

I have used the long value of timestamp you can use according to you case.

```
db.collection.update(
  {
    modelId: "5e68c7eaa0887971ea6ef54c",
    versionId: 999,
  },
  [
    {
      $set:{
        "oldValue":{
          $cond:[
            {
              $lt:[
                "timestamp",
                1598598257000
              ]
            },
            "green",
            "$oldValue"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      $set:{
        "newValue":{
          $cond:[
            {
              $gt:[
                "timestamp",
                1518598257000
              ]
            },
            "pink",
            "$newValue"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I did see the aggregate option, so I might be able to upgrade to **4.2** however when looking at the aggregation I'm not sure how I can do both conditions in one statement. Would you happen to know of any example using aggregates that have 2 conditions and each condition has its on $set ?

Comment: Hi @ODotN, I have updated the answer and manage to execute all in single query please have a look. :)

Comment: Tanks @Vijay - that seems to be the way to go. I'll give that a try